# Change input value to number schema - 1 1111 1111, Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I try to change input value from any possible characters to something similar to credit card number (so I want to accept only numbers and spaces). Main difference between my number and the credit card number typical regex is that I need to match 1 digit, then groups of 4 digits.

**Correct number: 1 1234 1234**

**Wrong numbers: 12 1234 123, 1234 1234 1**

I created regex than remove everything except numbers but have hard time to achieve above.

Got something like this:

```
this.rewardsNumber = this.rewardsNumber
  .replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
  .replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ')
  .trim();
```

This add spaces after every 4 digits. 
I want to add 1st space after 1st digit, and then after another 4 etc.

**UPDATE**

Found a solution that works good when inserting value to input (it adds space on the fly in correct places).

```
this.rewardsNumber = this.rewardsNumber
  .replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
  .replace(/(.{1})(.{1,3})/g, '$1 $2')
  .trim();
```

PS: Don't care about numbers after second 4th digit group. Input has limit in it.

Comment: Is the number of the digits always the same?

Comment: I found out something like this `.replace(/(.{1})(.{1,3})/g, '$1 $2')`

Answer (score 4):

You can just change the regex to deal differently with the first character:

```
this.rewardsNumber = this.rewardsNumber
  .replace(/\D/g, '')
  .replace(/(^.|.{4})/g, '$1 ')
  .trim();
```

```js
format.onclick = () => {
    rewardsNumber.value = rewardsNumber.value
      .replace(/\D/g, '')
      .replace(/(^.|.{4})/g, '$1 ')
      .trim();
};
```

```html
Number to format: <input id="rewardsNumber" size="100%">
<button id="format">Format</button>
```

As requested in comments, if you don't want to split a group at the end if that would result in a group with less than 4 digits, then you could use this regex:

```
this.rewardsNumber = this.rewardsNumber
  .replace(/\D/g, '')
  .replace(/(.)(...)(?=.)/g, '$1 $2')
  .trim();
```

```js
format.onclick = () => {
    rewardsNumber.value = rewardsNumber.value
      .replace(/\D/g, '')
      .replace(/(.)(...)(?=.)/g, '$1 $2')
      .trim();
};
```

```html
Number to format: <input id="rewardsNumber" size="100%">
<button id="format">Format</button>
```

Comment: Just a question to this solution - if the last few digits do not form a full 4-digit number, how can this regex be modified to append these "orphans" to the last group? E.g. if the input is: `1234567890` instead of making it `1 2345 6789 0` make it `1 2345 67890`? I tried making the quantifier `{4,7}` and make it lazy, but this didn't work.

Comment: @Asunez that's pretty easy with a lookahead. Check my answer, I added that option too

Comment: I updated my answer to keep digits together at the end if splitting them would result in a group of less than 4 digits. This means that the effect will only be visible when the input is more than 4 digits, otherwise they will just stick together in the output.

Answer (score 1):

There is a regex operator `^`, that means "start of the lane".

If you use ^\d it means it gets the first \d (number) of the line:

```
this.rewarsdNumber
.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
.replace(/(^\d|\d{4})/g, '$1 ')
.trim()
```

If you wanted to separate it only in groups or 4 or more (except the first one), so there is no group with less than 4, you could modify it like this to use a lookahead:

```
this.rewardsNumber
.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
.replace(/(^\d|\d{4}(?=\d{4}))/g, '$1 ')
.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this pattern for this.

```
this.rewardsNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/(.{1})(.{3})/g, '$1 $2').trim();
```

You can check below image to show my testing.[image]

Comment: Tried this, but when inserting value in input it produce effect after 5 digits inserted.

Comment: Sorry i am not understand. You mean when you enter less than 5 digit then your pattern is not generated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tranform any number length:

```js
s = '1234567890';
s = s.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
s = s.split('').reverse().join('');
s = s.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
s = s.trim();
s = s.split('').reverse().join('');
console.log(s);
```